Ratio of Normal pdf to cdf
I want to show that
$$\Bigl\lvert \frac{\phi(a)}{\Phi(a)} - \frac{\phi(b)}{\Phi(b)} \Bigr\rvert \leq |a-b|$$
where $\phi$ is the standard normal pdf, and $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

A plot of the Inverse Mills Ratio that appears on the left hand side, as shown at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166277/919, will suggest simple demonstrations.  Generally, when $f$ is a differentiable function with bounded derivative, say $|f^\prime(x)|\le M$ for all $x,$ then $|f(a)-f(b)| \le M|a-b|$ for all $a$ and $b$ (which is immediate from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

You want to prove that a function is lipschitz-1. So you need to prove that it's derivative is bounded. I'm not suggesting that it's trivial, but you should at least perform the elementary first steps and share where you are stuck before going to stack-exchange.

The underlying idea is captured by a general lemma:

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on an interval $I$ with $|f^\prime(z)|\lt 1$ everywhere on $I.$  Then for all $a,b\in I,$ $|f(a) - f(b)|\lt |a-b|.$

Proof.  By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $$|f(a) - f(b)| = \bigg|\int_b^a f^\prime(z)\,\mathrm dz\bigg| \le \bigg|\int_b^a |f^\prime(z)|\,\mathrm d z\bigg| \lt \bigg|\int_b^a \mathrm d z\bigg| = |a-b|,$$ QED.
Let $\phi$ be the standard Normal density (its value at any number $z$ is proportional to $e^{-z^2/2}$ by definition) and $\Phi$ its cumulative distribution function.  The statement in the question can be shown by applying the lemma to the function $f = \phi/\Phi.$  Among the many ways to do that, I present a completely elementary one that relies only on basic rules of differentiation and properties of $\phi$ and $\Phi.$
Specifically, what you need to know about the derivatives is
$$\Phi^\prime(z) = \phi(z);\quad \phi^\prime(z) = -z\phi(z)$$
(implying, for future reference, (i) both $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are infinitely differentiable and (ii) that  since $-z\phi(z)\gt 0$ for $z\lt 0,$ $\phi$ is an increasing function when $z$ is negative).
What you need to know about limiting properties is generally obvious from basic properties of the exponential function; the only one that might need demonstration is
$$\lim_{z\to-\infty} z\phi(z)\ \propto\ \lim_{z\to-\infty} \frac{z}{e^{z^2/2}} =  \lim_{z\to-\infty} \frac{1}{z e^{z^2/2}} = \lim_{z\to-\infty} \frac{0}{(1+z^2) e^{z^2/2}} = 0$$
(via two applications of L'Hopital's Rule).
Although some of the results obtained along the way are interesting, I don't think the process is very insightful, but here it is for completeness.

Because $\phi^\prime(z) = -z\phi(z),$ observe that for all $z,$
$$(\phi(z) + z\Phi(z))^\prime = -z\phi(z) +(\Phi(z) + z\phi(z)) = \Phi(z),$$
whence
$$G(z) := \phi(z) + z\Phi(z) =\int_{-\infty}^z (\phi(z) + z\Phi(z))^\prime\, \mathrm d z = \int_{-\infty}^z \Phi(z)\,\mathrm d z\ \gt\ 0.$$
(That's a handy expression for the integral of $\Phi,$ by the way.  From it you immediately obtain the expectation of the absolute value of a standard Normal variable, for instance, as equaling $2G(0)=2\phi(0) = \sqrt{2/\pi}.$)
Consider the related derivative as computed by the quotient rule:
$$\begin{aligned}
1 + \left(\frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(z)}\right)^\prime = \left(\frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(z)} + z\right)^\prime &= \left(\frac{\phi(z) + z\Phi(z)}{\Phi(z)}\right)^\prime \\
&= \frac{\Phi(z)\Phi(z) - (\phi(z) + z\Phi(z))\phi(z)}{\Phi(z)^2} \\
&= 1 - \left(\frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(z)}\right)\left(\frac{G(z)}{\Phi(z)}\right).
\end{aligned}$$
Because the amount subtracted from $1$ is positive, we have found

$$\left(\frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(z)}\right)^\prime \lt 0.\tag{*}$$

On the other hand, the numerator in the middle line of the preceding derivation is $$\Phi(z)^2 - G(z)\phi(z).$$  Take successive derivatives to find
$$\begin{aligned}
\left(\Phi(z)^2 - G(z)\phi(z)\right)^\prime &= \phi(z)\left(\Phi(z) +zG(z)\right);\\
\left(\Phi(z) +zG(z)\right)^\prime & = \phi(z) + G(z) + z\Phi(z) = 2G(z).
\end{aligned}$$
The right hand side of the first line is obviously positive for $z\gt 0$ because all its terms -- $\phi(z),$ $\Phi(z),$ $z,$ and $G(z)$ -- are positive.
Moreover, all the foregoing expressions (starting with $\Phi(z)^2 - G(z)\phi(z)$) have limiting values of zero as $z\to-\infty.$  Backing up from the last expression, where $2G(z)\gt 0,$ and remembering that $\phi$ is increasing for $z\lt 0,$ we learn that all these expressions are strictly increasing for negative $z,$ whence (since they begin at zero) are strictly positive.
We conclude that $\Phi(z)^2 - G(z)\phi(z) > 0$ for all $z.$  Dividing by the positive $\Phi(z)^2$ shows that for all $z,$

$$\left(\frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(z)}\right)^\prime \gt -1.\tag{**}$$

The results $(*)$ and $(**)$ show $\phi/\Phi$ satisfies the conditions of the lemma and we are done.

Related: Is the Inverse Mills Ratio Strictly Decreasing?.

@User1865345 That's a very clever demonstration!
